# Only support orientation for modal UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

My app has a UINavigationController, it does not support rotation. However I want to show a modal view controller on top of the navigationcontroller that should support rotation. Is this possible? I tried to override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` on the view controller that is shown modally but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have tried this [self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES>]; which will be on on top of your navigationcontroller. Now yourViewController's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation should return YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another post: [UIViewController inside a root ViewController not rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925268/uiviewcontroller-inside-a-root-viewcontroller-not-rotating)

The key is

`- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController`

and

`- (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers`

Answer (score 1):

I think that in addition to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` of the view controller that is shown modally returning `YES`, your navigation controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` should be overridden to return `YES` when that modal view controller is showing, and `NO` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your device generates device orientation notifications (UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification):

make sure:

[generatesDeviceOrientationNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) is set to true

From the Apple docs:

"The window object does much of the work associated with changing the current orientation. However, it works in conjunction with the root view controller to determine whether an orientation change should occur at all and, if so, what additional methods should be called to respond to the change. If this controller is a container, it may rely on a child to decide whether the orientation should occur."

So if you root view controller (UINavigationController?) doesn't support rotations then this might be set to false when your app starts. In which case you will need to turn it back on when appropriate:

```
UIDevice myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice]; 
[myDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```