# childViewControllers not receiving rotation events

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I've got a system of parent/child view controllers that looks like this

```
-- (Parent) RootViewController
      -- (Child) ChildController
              -- (Child) GrandChildController1
              -- (Child) GrandChildController2
```

Basically, I've got a root view controller with a childViewController. That childViewController acts as a parentViewController for a couple other controllers. Now, I'd like to allow one of those GrandChildViewControllers to rotate. But this is the ONLY controller in the hierarchy who is allowed to rotate.

I'm adding child view controllers to the hierarchy like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:_childViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_childViewController.view];
```

Now, when the device rotates, my first childViewController is receiving rotation events, but none of the children of that controller (the grand child view controllers) are receiving rotation events. Anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling the super methods from your rotation callback overrides?

Comment: You should also be calling [_childViewController didMoveToParentViewController], but I don't know if that will fix your problem.

Comment: check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8927955/2315974

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for the heads up. I've added this and unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @SanjitSaluja no i am not, which methods do u mean?

Comment: If you override any UIViewController rotation method (willRotate/didRotate) etc. you must call super.

Comment: no i am not using those methods i'm using shouldAutorotate (ios6) and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(iOS 5)

Answer (score 1):

Things to look out for:

- In iOS 6 you also need to override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` - overriding `shouldAutorotate` is not enough.
- In iOS 5 if a parent VC returns `NO` for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` it will cancel the rotation for child VCs. I'm not sure if the iOS 6 autorotate mechanism behaves similarly.

From your comments I would guess that you are lacking `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. If my guess is wrong then it might help if you showed us your implementation of the autorotate methods in all of your controllers.